# R - Counting elements in a vector

Tags: r, vector, count, element, vctrs

is there a way to count elements in a vector, without considering its unique values?
For example, I have a vector  `vec <- as.vector(c("A","A","B","B","A","A","B","B"))`.
I want to count the elements in the vector so it will return a vector of `[1] 2 2 2 2` .

I have tried using the `vec_count` function in the `vctrs` package:

```
my_vec <- as.vector(c("A","A","B","B","A","A","B","B"))
my_count <- vec_count(my_vec, sort = "key")
my_count$count
[1] 4 4
```

But this function considers the unique elements in the vector, which is not what I want. Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: I think you are looking for `rle(vec)$lengths`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are counting continual sequence here, we can use `rle`.

```
rle(vec)$lengths
#[1] 2 2 2 2
```

Something similar with `data.table` `rleid` :

```
table(data.table::rleid(vec))
#1 2 3 4 
#2 2 2 2
```